# What is easiest way to deal with converting 0/1 to False/True in EF 4.x?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

The stored Proc returns a column with the value to be either 0 or 1 without converting to BIT. In my POCO, if I declare the field as

```
public bool MyColumn {get; set;}
```

I am getting this error:

```
The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid.
```

This actually makes sense since EF recognizes the returned value as an integer.

I am wondering that is there any easy way to (add annotation or use fluent api maybe) automatically convert 0/1 to False/True in the mapping behind the scene without touching the Proc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already touched on it.  Convert the return value to a BIT.

Comment: Boo is correct. If you don't have access to the stored procedure to change the return type of the column to bit, you'll have to change the  type of the property to an `int`, and then check for equality to 0.

Comment: I had a similar issue to this - at the start of the stored proc I had defined a temp table with a column of type Bit. When returning results, I was unioning a select from the temp table, with another query where the value for the bit column was just set to "0". I was getting the same error as above, and ended up resolving it by using cast(bitcolumn as bit) - this then resolved the error, and I didn't need to change code to work around this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is to have another Property to represent the Boolean representation . Decorate it with `NotMapped` attribute so that EF won't consider it for Mapping. Do and If condition and return `true /false` based on the value of Other property.

```
public Class Customer
{

  [NotMapped]
  public bool MyColumnBool 
  {
      get
      {
         return (MyColumn ==1);
      }
  }

  public int MyColumn {get; set;}
  // other properties

}
```

Comment: +1, though I would return `MyColumn != 0` just in case truth is really non-zero.

Answer (score 29):

Another option is to return a BIT from the stored procedure so you don't need to cast anything at C# side or use any weird decoration. This means, you can cast the integer value to BIT in T-SQL like I do below:

```
select col1, col2, CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as colWithBit
FROM table1
```

Comment: As far I know, from SQL server point of view Cast it is the best option.

Answer (score 6):

In your `ApplicationDbContext` (the class that inherits from `DbContext`) you can use Fluent Api to convert values for the database.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  modelBuilder.Entity<TheNameOfYourModelClass>()
    .Property(p => p.MyColumn)
    .HasConversion(
       v => v ? 1 : 0,
       v => (v == 1));
}
```

Now, your database will contain `1` when inserting a `true` for `MyColumn` and vice-versa. When reading from your database `1` will be converted to `true` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

building on what @jimmy provided, could also define the ValueConverter separately and then apply across multiple entities/properties:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var boolConverter = new ValueConverter<bool, int>(
        v => v ? 1 : 0,
        v => (v == 1) ? true : false);

    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.ClrType == typeof(bool))
                property.SetValueConverter(boolConverter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Use `System.Convert.ToBoolean(int)`

Comment: That's easy. Just fork and update the EF source code to do so, and when your pull request is accepted, EF will automatically do `System.Convert.ToBoolean(int)` while materialising query results.