# Entity Framework Database first and SQLite Boolean error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I've created a model(edmx) connecting to a sqlite database(not by choice). I'm having issues with the boolean fields. When I query the table using DB browser for SQLite, the 'boolean' fields have "t" or "f". When I call the web api url, it returns:

```
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.


"ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToBoolean(String source)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToBoolean(Object obj, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean viaFramework)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.GetBoolean(SQLiteStatement stmt, Int32 index)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.GetValue(SQLiteStatement stmt, SQLiteConnectionFlags flags, Int32 index, SQLiteType typ)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()"
```

I have tried to do a (true/false)conversion using this answer [What is easiest way to deal with converting 0/1 to False/True in EF 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783226/what-is-easiest-way-to-deal-with-converting-0-1-to-false-true-in-ef-4-x)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: OK after digging a little more...even though the columns are populated with 't' or 'f'...the entity object is returning null values for the column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I have found an answer after a lot of digging. You will need to change the property type in the EDMX file. Right click on your EDMX file and click 'open with...'. Open file with xml editor. You will need to locate the property and change the type (I changed mine to string since the columns are 't' and 'f'). You will need to make the change for the scalarProperty as well. After that, update your model's property type. Cheers!